# style all pages with external css stylesheet

Tags: hyperlink, external

I am trying to style all my pages but the output only styles main html file I double checked everything all my links are correct and external style link is between head tag I would appreciate anyone that can help me out thanks

Comment: Are you including the link to the external stylesheet in the `<head>` of all of your pages? It would help if you'd please add your code to the question.

Comment: <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">